# What is the xpath syntax to get the 1st, 2nd and 3rd occurrence of an element within another element

Tags: xml, xpath, asp-classic, jscript

I have the following xml document (I have cleared out the irrelevant data):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NewOrderNotification xmlns="http://payments.amazon.com/checkout/2008-11-30/">
  <ProcessedOrder>
    <ShippingServiceLevel>blah</ShippingServiceLevel>
    <ProcessedOrderItems>
      <ProcessedOrderItem>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>blah</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <Price>
          <Amount>0.2</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
        </Price>
        <ItemCharges>
          <Component>
            <Type>Principal</Type>
            <Charge>
              <Amount>0.2</Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            </Charge>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>Shipping</Type>
            <Charge>
              <Amount>0.95</Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            </Charge>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>PrincipalPromo</Type>
            <Charge>
              <Amount>0.0</Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            </Charge>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>ShippingPromo</Type>
            <Charge>
              <Amount>0.0</Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            </Charge>
          </Component>
        </ItemCharges>
        <ShippingCustomData>null</ShippingCustomData>
      </ProcessedOrderItem>
    </ProcessedOrderItems>
  </ProcessedOrder>
</NewOrderNotification>
```

I want to know the xpath syntax for getting each of the values within the 5 different `<Amount>` elements:

Namely how do I extract each of the following:

- NewOrderNotification - ProcessedOrder - ProcessedOrderItems - ProcessedOrderItem - Price - Amount
- NewOrderNotification - ProcessedOrder - ProcessedOrderItems - ProcessedOrderItem - ItemCharges - Component(with type=Principle) - Charge - Amount
- NewOrderNotification - ProcessedOrder - ProcessedOrderItems - ProcessedOrderItem - ItemCharges - Component(with type=Shipping) - Charge - Amount
- NewOrderNotification - ProcessedOrder - ProcessedOrderItems - ProcessedOrderItem - ItemCharges - Component(with type=PrincipalPromo) - Charge - Amount
- NewOrderNotification - ProcessedOrder - ProcessedOrderItems - ProcessedOrderItem - ItemCharges - Component(with type=ShippingPromo) - Charge - Amount

**Please note** the xmlns in the root element.

This is the JScript code I'm using to extract elements:

```
var xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:a='http://payments.amazon.com/checkout/2008-11-30/'");
xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
var node = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("XPATH_IN_HERE");
return node.text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first amount you can get with just:

```
//Price/Amount/text()
#=> "0.2"
```

For the other four, you can use the text of the preceding sibling `Type` element to get their values:

```
//Charge[preceding-sibling::Type="Principal"]/Amount/text()
#=> "0.2"

//Charge[preceding-sibling::Type="Shipping"]/Amount/text()
#=> "0.95"

//Charge[preceding-sibling::Type="PrincipalPromo"]/Amount/text()
#=> "0.0"

//Charge[preceding-sibling::Type="ShippingPromo"]/Amount/text()
#=> "0.0"
```

I think that does it. (Let me know if I misunderstood your question.)

Comment: I have edited my question to include the piece of code that I am using.  Maybe its my code, but I can't get the first of these to work.  I haven't tried the others yet.  I've also tried //a:NewOrderNotification/ProcessedOrder/ProcessedOrderItems/ProcessedOrderItem/Price/Amount with no success

Comment: This might help - I have removed the xmlns from the xml and removed the setProperty line from my code then your answer works.  So what modification to the xpath would I need to deal with the xmlns?

Comment: Sorry I'm using ruby/Nokogiri, so a bit hard to compare, but I also found that it worked after removing the namespace first. With the namespace, in nokogiri, you have to append `xmnls:` to every tag, e.g.: `//xmlns:Charge[preceding-sibling::xmlns:Type="ShippingPromo"]/xmlns:Amount/text()`, etc.

Comment: p.p.s. what is the `a` in `xmlns:a`? what if you just do: `xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns='http://payments.amazon.com/checkout/2008-11-30/'");`

Comment: doesn't like it without the a - I believe the a is just an alias for the long namespace. Tried //xmlns:Charge[preceding-sibling::xmlns:Type="ShippingPromo"]/xmlns:Amount/text‌​() and still no go, but I think we might be getting closer

Comment: Ah bingo - got there in the end: //a:Charge[preceding-sibling::a:Type=\"Principal\"]/a:Amount   Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Or if you like absolute paths abbreviated

```
'/NewOrderNotification/ProcessedOrder/ProcessedOrderItems/ProcessedOrderItem/ItemCharges/Component[Type="Shipping"]/Charge/Amount/text()'
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my quick and dirty xpaths in the following xslt script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:test="http://payments.amazon.com/checkout/2008-11-30/">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Standard if you can define namespaces -->
    <xsl:variable name="amount1" select="//test:Price/test:Amount"/>
    <!-- for cases with namespace problems -->
    <xsl:variable name="amount2" select="//*[local-name() = 'Component'][1]/*[local-name() = 'Charge']/*[local-name() = 'Amount']"/>
    <!-- you can add the other in the same way -->


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <test>
        <variable1><xsl:value-of select="$amount1"/></variable1>    
        <variable2><xsl:value-of select="$amount2"/></variable2>
        </test> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Graham In unix like systems you can call ...
xsltproc myXSLTStylesheet.xsl yourXMLFile.xml

Where do you want use the xpath?

Comment: I'm using it in Classic ASP (JScript) so unix is no good to me

Comment: copy the xpaths from the variables amount* ... the second one is more namespace independent